# Читаются не все символы кириллицы в консоли NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Программа не читает символы казахского языка (вместо них идут знаки вопроса), например "ғ", при этом корректно выводит символы русского алфавита, а так же некоторые символы вроде "љ". Все они относятся к кириллице по Юникоду. Использовал кодировку windows-1251, пробовал в свойствах проекта ставить UTF-8, но он отказался вообще что-либо принимать и просто переводился на новую строку.

```
package la6;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class La6 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in,  "windows-1251");
    System.out.println("Enter ID's name: ");
    String str  = in.nextLine();

    if (isValidIdentifier(str)) {
      System.out.println("«" + str + "» - допустимое значение");  
    } else
    {
      System.out.println("«" + str + "» - недопустимое значение");
    }
    System.out.println();    
}    
public static boolean isValidIdentifier(String str) {       
    if (!str.matches("[$_\u0401-\u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+[$_0-9\u0401-\u04F9\u0041-\uFB06]+")) {
    return false;
    } 

    String[] keyWords = {"boolean","volatile","else","instanceof","switch","true","goto","abstract","enum","int","static","false","break","assert","extends","interface","strictfp","null","continue","byte","final","long","super","do","case","finally","native","synchronized","double","catch","float","new","throw","protected","char","for","package","throws","this","class","if","private","transient","short","const","implements","public","try","while","default","import","return","void", "/", "\\","\""};
          if (Arrays.asList(keyWords).contains(str))
    {               
        return false;
    }
return true;
}
}
```

Результат:

```
run:
Enter ID's name: 
ырҒ
«ыр?» - недопустимое значение
```

Comment: Возможно используемый шрифт не содержит нужных символов. Попробуйте сменить шрифт.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov Не то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовал менять кодировку в свойствах проект и в самом коде добавлять - не помогло.
Вообщем решил так: Запускаем блокнот от имени админа -> перейдем папку, где установлена NetBeans. И в этой папке далее перейдем в каталог *etc*, в котором будет файл *netbeans.conf*. То есть путь к данному файлу будет примерно следующим: *C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\etc\netbeans.conf*. В этом файле изменим параметр `netbeans_default_options`. По умолчанию он имеет следующее значение:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

В конце добавим опцию `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, не забыв вписать её под кавычки. То есть в итоге получится:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: `-J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` помогло?

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov , да